# How to keep track of elasticsearch requests

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic cluster I have 2 indices. I need to keep track of the requests that come to these indices. For example I have customer and product indices. When a new customer document added to customer index, I need to get the id of the document that added and its body.
Another example when a product document is updated I also need the id of that product and its body or what changed in that document.
My elasticsearch version is 7.17
(I am writing in node.js if you have an code examples or solution I would be appreciated)

Comment: You could query elastic and sort based on the timestamp if you want to track the indexing/updating.

Comment: @hamidbayat thank you for your answer but I also need to track the deleted documents do you have any idea for that too? As far I know if it is deleted there is no timestamp for it because it is gone.

Comment: DELETE API should not be allowed to be used by users. You must proxy DELETE requests and save their requests on another index. Or you can update the document and add a field like "deleted":true

Answer (score 1):

you can do this via the [Elasticsearch slow log](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/index-modules-slowlog.html), where you reduce the timing to a 0 so it tracks everything, or via some other proxy that intercepts the requests. Elasticsearch doesn't do this out of the box though unfortunately

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I use slow log with node.js ?

Comment: what do you mean "with node.js"?

Comment: I meant how can I implement the logic in node.js, for example how can I enable and disable slow log with node.js code but I figure it out thank you.

Comment: good to hear, might be worth sharing your solution for someone in future! :)